# Special characters in usernames making it hard to reply to comments on mobile?

Tags: support, comments, mobile-web, display-names, comment-replies

Sometimes users have special characters in their usernames like this `ϟ` or this `ƞ` that make it hard to mension them in comments like to reply. Think there's a user with the username: `Ligtningϟ`. Is there any way to make this easier? If I'm on mobile I won't always be able to see the autocomplete popup and I won't be able to put in the special character? How can I then input the username?

Comment: When such users are on the comment thread, starting the `@` will show them and you can select the name - it will autocomplete.

Comment: @KateGregory I'm asking for on mobile